# Bitbucket Pipeline With Selenium Hub Not Working? Have it working locally with docker

Tags: python, docker, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I've tried to replicate the bitbucket pipeline build locally - and can get it working so my integration tests are running and passing with Docker. However once I push to Bitbucket those same tests fail.

I think the answer is something simple - I just can't figure it out.

It's a Django project/app and I use Selenium to launch firefox and chrome browsers to test against.

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` and this works locally:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  python:
    image: "hanny/python:3.8"
    build:
      context: ./docker
      dockerfile: python.dock
    volumes:
      - ".:/project_dir"
    environment:
      - DJANGO_DEBUG=True
      - myproject_SECRET_KEY=1234_secret_key_4321
      - BITBUCKET_CI=True
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - hub
  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: hub
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: hub
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

The `python.dock` file is very simple:

```
FROM python:3.8
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN pip install virtualenv

CMD ["tail", "-F", "-n0", "/etc/hosts"]
```

Then I launch an interactive bash shell for that container and install requirements and run pytest.

My `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file is also pretty simple/straightforward:

```
image: python:3.8

pipelines:
  branches:
    dev:
      - step:
          name: Build project & run pytest
          caches:
            - pip
          services:
            - hub
          script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
            - pip install virtualenv
            - virtualenv venv
            - source venv/bin/activate
            - apt-get install gcc libc-dev g++ libffi-dev libxml2 unixodbc-dev gnupg2 -y
            - pip install -r requirements-dev.txt
            - pytest
definitions:
  services:
    firefox:
      image: selenium/node-firefox
      volumes:
        - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
      depends_on:
        - hub
      environment:
        HUB_HOST: hub
    chrome:
      image: selenium/node-chrome
      volumes:
        - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
      depends_on:
        - hub
      environment:
        HUB_HOST: hub
    hub:
      image: selenium/hub
      ports:
        - "4444:4444"
```

I utilize `pytest` for my testing and in the setup of the browser for my tests it looks like this:

```
    HUB_URL = "http://hub:4444/wd/hub"
    chrome_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
    browser = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor=HUB_URL, desired_capabilities=chrome_capabilities
    )
```

This launches the appropriate browser and my tests all pass no problem using Docker locally. I believe it's because I use `links` to attach the two containers to each other - so I can use the service name in the URL and it gets routed appropriately.

When I run my CI on Bitbucket the tests fail.

This is the failure message:

```
        try:
>           conn = connection.create_connection(
                (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
            )
venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:159: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
address = ('hub', 4444), timeout = <object object at 0x7f8bd0757630>
source_address = None, socket_options = [(6, 1, 1)]
    def create_connection(
        address,
        timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
        source_address=None,
        socket_options=None,
    ):
        """Connect to *address* and return the socket object.
    
        Convenience function.  Connect to *address* (a 2-tuple ``(host,
        port)``) and return the socket object.  Passing the optional
        *timeout* parameter will set the timeout on the socket instance
        before attempting to connect.  If no *timeout* is supplied, the
        global default timeout setting returned by :func:`getdefaulttimeout`
        is used.  If *source_address* is set it must be a tuple of (host, port)
        for the socket to bind as a source address before making the connection.
        An host of '' or port 0 tells the OS to use the default.
        """
    
        host, port = address
        if host.startswith("["):
            host = host.strip("[]")
        err = None
    
        # Using the value from allowed_gai_family() in the context of getaddrinfo lets
        # us select whether to work with IPv4 DNS records, IPv6 records, or both.
```

I believe the reason for this has to do with using `http://hub:4444/wd/hub` as the URL.

In pipelines what should I be using for that URL? I've tried `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` with no luck.

I am using Docker to try to replicate the Pipelines environment locally so I don't burn through minutes if not necessary. But now that it works locally - I'm at a loss on how to get this going in Bitbucket Pipelines.

Comment: I've got the same issue as you I think.... Did you ever find a solution? From what I can tell the port is being mapped to the server rather than the host container and so it's not available to the container.

Comment: We ended up going a different direction with the project and creating an image that had various browsers installed locally. It is a gross solution, but has managed to allow us to test locally and see errors before pushing to the CI and wasting minutes. Never did get this figured out - if you figure it out, please post! I agree with your assertion about what the possible issue is though.